# Flutter App closes immediately when i tap on join meeting button using jitsi_meet_wrapper

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, proguard, jitsi-meet

I have configured pro-guard.pro file but still doesn't work, I am using jitsi_meet_wrapper package.

I have even included `Manifest>application` section of the manifest file

```
<service
            android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Am getting this line in debug console.

```
E/JitsiMeetSDK(14331):  ... 9 more
I/JitsiMeetSDK(14331): JitsiConnectionService onAbort 6A057729-687E-4F5F-B5E1-F4E173DF65AD
D/JitsiMeetSDK(14331): JitsiConnectionService onStateChanged: DISCONNECTED 6A057729-687E-4F5F-B5E1-F4E173DF65AD
D/EGL_emulation(14331): app_time_stats: avg=17.40ms min=5.07ms max=55.80ms count=45
I/Process (14331): Sending signal. PID: 14331 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Anyone with the fix?
Please help, thank you

I have tried to add this line in `android>app>build,gradle` but it didn't work either

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // added this for jitsi_meet
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive = true }
}
```

Comment: Can you run "flutter pub outdated" in your project directory to see if the version of jitsi_meet_wrapper is compatible

Comment: I have found out that the issue was the notification icon! so i added it and it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across a solution:

1. Open your `project>android` using android studio (Select android folder underneath the project name) wait for build to finish.
2. `android>res` right click on res folder in android project and choose image asset from new section
3. Create icon with following config
   `Name`: ic_notification
   `Icon Type`: Notification Icons

Issue will be resolved.